# Fortran95 -- Reading from a formatted text file

Tags: fortran

I need to read some values from a table.  These are the first five rows, to give you some idea of what it should look like:

```
1        +           3          98           96        1
2        +         337        2799         2463        1
3        +        2801        3733          933        1
4        +        3734        5020         1287        1
5        +        5234        5530          297        1
```

My interest is in the first four columns of each row.  I need to read these into arrays.  I used the following code:

```
program ----
implicit none

integer, parameter :: totbases = 4639675, totgenes = 4395
integer :: codtot, ks
integer, dimension(totgenes) :: ngene, lend, rend
character :: genome*4639675, sign*4

open(1,file='e_coli_g_info')
open(2,file='e_coli_g_str')

do ks = 1, totgenes
 read(1,100) ngene(ks),sign(ks:ks),lend(ks), rend(ks)
end do
100 format(1x,i4,8x,a1, 2(5x,i7), 22x)



do ks = 1, 100
 write(*,*) ngene(ks), sign(ks:ks),lend(ks), rend(ks)
end do

end program
```

The loop at the end of the program is to print the first hundred entries to test that they are being read correctly.  The problem is that I am getting this garbage (the fourth row is the problem):

```
1 +           3   757934891
2 +         337   724249387
3 +        2801   757803819
4 +        3734   757803819
5 +        5234   757935405
```

Clearly, the fourth column is way off.  In fact, I cannot find these values anywhere in the file that I am reading from.  I am using the gfortran compiler for Ubuntu 12.04.  I would greatly appreciate if somebody would point me in the right direction.  I'm sure it's likely that I'm missing something very obvious because I'm new at Fortran.

Comment: sure the original file is only spaces not tabs. In any case a workaround is to read the whole line as a string then do a list directed internal read from the + position  onward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran formats are (traditionally, there's some newer stuff that I won't go into here) fixed format, that is, they are best suited for file formats with fixed columns. I.e. column N always starts at character position M, no ifs or buts. If your file format is more "free format"-like, that is, columns are separated by whitespace, it's often easier and more robust to read data using list formatting. That is, try to do your read loop as

```
do ks = 1, totgenes
  read(1, *) ngene(ks), sign(ks:ks), lend(ks), rend(ks)
end do
```

Also, as a general advice, when opening your own files, start from unit 10 and go upwards from there. Fortran implementations typically use some of the low-numbered units for standard input, output, and error (a common choice is units 1, 5, and 6). You probably don't want to redirect those.

PS 2: I haven't tried your code, but it seems that you have a bounds overflow in the sign variable. It's declared of length 4, but then you assign to index ks which goes all the way up to totgenes. As you're using gfortran on Ubuntu 12.04 (that is, gfortran 4.6), when developing compile with options "-O1 -Wall -g -fcheck=all"

Comment: This advice (changing the file numbers to 10 and 11 and fixing the bounds overflow) fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: for the record the list directed read of an unquoted string is a f90+ feature.  Since we have it standard now i'd call this the preferred approach, even though the file appears to be fixed format.